# Unity2D: Sprite Mesh Lighting Issue

Tags: unity, shaders, sprites, lighting, global-illumination

I am trying to make my 2D mesh render sprites with the **same brightness** as the original file.

On the below picture, the mesh on the left is **darker** than the UI Image on the right, which is an exact likeness of the original file. **How can I make the mesh as bright as the Image?**

So far, I've been looking into the following potential culprits:

- Shader attached to the Mesh
- Global lighting settings
- Mesh renderer lighting settings

[image]

The above image is with *Environment Lighting > Ambient Color* at **#FFFFFF**.

*Environment Lighting > Ambient Color > Intensity* doesn't help.
Increasing the shader's emissions can offset the darkness but it's not an ideal solution.

*All other lighting settings both globally and on the Mesh Renderer are default.*

At this point, I'm lost :/
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was the **shader** ***type***.
Changing **Shader** Standard -> **Shader** Unlit/Texture, solved the issue!

[image]